# R won't let me download packages, seems to be stuck trying to install ggsurvfit?

Tags: r, ggplot2, installation, permissions

I was struggling to install ggsurvfit earlier, and in troubleshooting I deleted its dependencies. I went to reinstall ggplot2 and got this. It seems like I can't install anything now! I have no clue what happened. I am in administrator, have constantly restarted, and have RTools40. Is there some mistake I am missing?

Take a look at my output please. Also it pops up asking "Do you want to install from sources the package which needs compilation?" with y or n as options. Doesn't work with either response.

```
> install.packages("ggplot2")
Error in install.packages : Updating loaded packages
> install.packages("ggplot2")
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/CLAHM/Documents/R/win-library/4.0’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
also installing the dependencies ‘cli’, ‘lifecycle’, ‘rlang’, ‘vctrs’


  There are binary versions available but the source versions are later:
          binary source needs_compilation
cli        3.2.0  3.6.2              TRUE
lifecycle  1.0.1  1.0.4             FALSE
rlang      1.0.2  1.1.3              TRUE
vctrs      0.4.1  0.6.5              TRUE
ggplot2    3.3.5  3.4.4             FALSE

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/4.0/cli_3.2.0.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 1255499 bytes (1.2 MB)
downloaded 1.2 MB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/4.0/rlang_1.0.2.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 1718546 bytes (1.6 MB)
downloaded 1.6 MB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/4.0/vctrs_0.4.1.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 1569486 bytes (1.5 MB)
downloaded 1.5 MB

package ‘cli’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
Warning in install.packages :
  cannot remove prior installation of package ‘cli’
Warning in install.packages :
  problem copying C:\Users\CLAHM\Documents\R\win-library\4.0\00LOCK\cli\libs\x64\cli.dll to C:\Users\CLAHM\Documents\R\win-library\4.0\cli\libs\x64\cli.dll: Permission denied
Warning in install.packages :
  restored ‘cli’
package ‘rlang’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
Warning in install.packages :
  cannot remove prior installation of package ‘rlang’
Warning in install.packages :
  problem copying C:\Users\CLAHM\Documents\R\win-library\4.0\00LOCK\rlang\libs\x64\rlang.dll to C:\Users\CLAHM\Documents\R\win-library\4.0\rlang\libs\x64\rlang.dll: Permission denied
Warning in install.packages :
  restored ‘rlang’
package ‘vctrs’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
Warning in install.packages :
  cannot remove prior installation of package ‘vctrs’
Warning in install.packages :
  problem copying C:\Users\CLAHM\Documents\R\win-library\4.0\00LOCK\vctrs\libs\x64\vctrs.dll to C:\Users\CLAHM\Documents\R\win-library\4.0\vctrs\libs\x64\vctrs.dll: Permission denied
Warning in install.packages :
  restored ‘vctrs’

The downloaded binary packages are in
    C:\Users\CLAHM\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpqUtJt1\downloaded_packages
installing the source packages ‘lifecycle’, ‘ggplot2’

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/lifecycle_1.0.4.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 107656 bytes (105 KB)
downloaded 105 KB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/ggplot2_3.4.4.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 3159578 bytes (3.0 MB)
downloaded 3.0 MB

* installing *source* package 'lifecycle' ...
** package 'lifecycle' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
** R
** inst
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
Error in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]) : 
  namespace 'rlang' 1.0.2 is being loaded, but >= 1.1.0 is required
Calls: <Anonymous> ... withCallingHandlers -> loadNamespace -> namespaceImport -> loadNamespace
Execution halted
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package 'lifecycle'
* removing 'C:/Users/CLAHM/Documents/R/win-library/4.0/lifecycle'
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘lifecycle’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependency 'lifecycle' is not available for package 'ggplot2'
* removing 'C:/Users/CLAHM/Documents/R/win-library/4.0/ggplot2'
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘ggplot2’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘C:\Users\CLAHM\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpqUtJt1\downloaded_packages’
> library(ggplot2)
Error in library(ggplot2) : there is no package called ‘ggplot2’
```

Comment: This is a confusing problem, I hate to recommend it but have you attempted to remove R and reinstall a fresh version?  Also, I would suggest always answering "No" to the question: "Do you want to install from sources the package which needs compilation?"